# What is the difference between 2 phase locking and strict 2 phase locking?

Tags: database-design, transaction

[2 phase locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking) is used to ensure isolation of database transactions (by ensuring [serializability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability)). But there is another term called `Strict 2 phase locking`. I find it hard to understand the difference.

What is the difference between the two?